# Inserted JavaScript by usercontrol invokes only on first page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have used a user control to get data from database and render it as MegaMenu anchors.
In code-behind file I have got data and rendered it by using a literal.

The megamenu.js file (containging myMega.Init method) has been inserted into header element

I have added following script tag into .ascx file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  myMega.Init("mer_id", "anchor_id", "click");
</script>
```

I have several .aspx files which have same master page. The master page registers the User Control and contains following tag exact before .

```
 <uc:MegaMenu id="anchors" runat="server"></uc:MegaMenu>
```

the problem is the myMega.Init only invokes when I go to firstpage.aspx. I have debugged by hitting f12 and choosing debugg Script. the init file invokes only first time (firstpage) not other pages. thank you for your help.

Comment: did you try load instead

Comment: do you mean body onload()?

Answer (score 0):

are mer_id and anchor_id elements' ids and what .Init does?

Comment: yes, mer_id and anchor_id are elements and init does a lot, it adds attributes and make a javascript object .

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery library you could put your code in ready event

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  myMega.Init("mer_id", "anchor_id", "click");
});
</script>
```